# Filling out a country with hubs

Tags: qgis

[image: Germany with hubs]

I'm really new to QGIS

1 - How can I get the radius for each Hub so it fills out my entire country?
Is there a plugin for that. Because with Puffers I have to guess myself and it doesn't really work out with the distances which brings me to my second question

2 - I have chosen DHDN / Soldner Berlin as my CRS. Is that right to get distances in metres for Germany?

Comment: It looks as though you want to generate Voronoi polygons, which is available in Vector>Geometry Tools within QGIS. Once the Voronoi Diagram is generated you could then clip to the country outline. (This will also eliminate the need to define units, although it's always important to understand the CRS you are working in)

Comment: @ProudGIS, sounds like an answer

Answer (score 5):

I'm not 100% sure of what you are asking, hence leaving a comment initially rather than posting an answer. It looks as though you want to generate Voronoi polygons, which is available in Vector>Geometry Tools within QGIS.

[image]

Once the Voronoi Diagram is generated you could then clip to the country outline. (This will also eliminate the need to define units, although it's always important to understand the CRS you are working in)

I think Voronoi is generated on a bounding box or convex hull of your points so you may need to perform some additional merging with your boundary polygon to get the final ouput.